# Scrollbar doens't scroll on Chrome

Tags: css

With Chrome 42 and OSX 10.10.3, the scrollbar of the iframe contained in this page (https://uala-frontend.herokuapp.com/venues/5/) doesn't scroll.

Despite, the content inside the iframe scroll. Why?

Instead with Firefox, Safari or Chrome for mobile it works perfectly.

Comment: The scrollbar in the `<iframe>` scrolls in my (desktop) Chrome browser on Windows 7. It could be an `overflow-y: hidden;` or something similar that is set in the Chrome browser for OSX. Did you check if there were any `overflow` properties set?

Comment: Checked, but there's nothing particular :/

Answer (score 0):

changing the color of the scrollbar, it works...

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #E0E0E0;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #D92428;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.4);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background: #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```